# String starting with + operator doesn't match with database String value

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to compare incoming sms numbers with database saved number. if they are same then show a Toast. It works fine for simple numbers like 9 or any others but not with **+** operator.

When we recieved a message from a number it consists of country code like for pakistan +92XXXXXXXXXX. I've saved it to database but when message recieved with the same number then it doesn't match.

I checked on emulator it works fine for simple number like message from 9 etc. but not with + operator. kidnly help.

**Error found on Log:** 
Index 0 requested with size of 0

My database tabe:

```
// Create statement for block_list table
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
            + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0,"
            + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST + " TEXT,"
            + TIME_BLOCK_LIST + " TEXT)";
```

comparing statement:

```
// Select all Blocked Numbers
    public Cursor compareToBlockList(String originatingAddress){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST + " FROM " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
                    + " WHERE " + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST + "=" + originatingAddress, null);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("compare to Block list", " is" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return  cursor;
    }
```

calling function:

```
Cursor cursor = dbManagement.compareToBlockList(originatingAddress);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbManagement.ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST));

                        Toast.makeText(context, "found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

database value:

[image: database]

**Error found on Log:** 
Index 0 requested with size of 0

Comment: not full, i used emulator to send message from +92 number which saved in database. I also tried with full number but same errors occur

Comment: specific number which are in database.

Comment: the picture in my question shows database\

Comment: do you understand my problem? @MikeM.

Comment: my code works fine for originatingAddress 1 but not for +92, +1, +9. this value shows in pictures @MikeM.

Comment: I've edit picture. when i recieved message form +923087476605 then it can't match with database numbers. @MikeM.

Comment: thanks @MikeM. i got answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change to 
`cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST + " FROM " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST + " WHERE " + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS_BLOCKlIST + "= '" + originatingAddress + "'", null);`

(surrounded with apostrophes)